# Displaying lookups as urls in a Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lookup

I'm trying to create a simple component which beholds a list of contacts. The thing is I would like its name to be a link to the actual record. Is there any simple way to do this?

I working with an example from the docs, simple and easy:

**Component**

```
<aura:component description="MyComponent" controller="MyComponentController">
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.data}" columns="{!v.columns}" keyField="Id"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set('v.columns', [
                {label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'},
                {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email'}
            ]);

        helper.getData(cmp);
    }
})
```

**Helper**

```
({
    getData : function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get('c.getContacts'); // Just a simple SOQL.

        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();

            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set('v.mydata', response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else if(state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.error(errors);
            }
        }));

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public with sharing class MyComponentController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<SObject> getContacts(String currentContactId) {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 10];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the apex controller code as well. I can just copy paste and try :) have an idea of how this can be achieved.

Comment: @RedDevil there you go! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Manjot Singh's answer, I came to a solution which solves exactly what I needed: Creating a column of type `url` for which we also define a field name through the `typeAttributes`. In other words:

```
{
    label: 'Contact Name', 
    fieldName: 'url', 
    type: 'url', 
    typeAttributes: { 
        label: { fieldName: 'Name'}, 
        target: '_blank'
    }
}
```

Now, the full code would look as follows:

**Controller**

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var button = {label: 'Open', name: 'openRecord', title: 'openRecord', disabled: false, value: 'test' };

            cmp.set('v.mycolumns', [
                    {label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'url', type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'Name' },target: '_blank' } },
                    {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'},
                    {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email'}
                ]);

            helper.getData(cmp);
    }
})
```

**Helper**

```
({
    getData : function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get('c.getContacts');

        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();

            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                var mydata = response.getReturnValue();
                var formattedData;

                if(mydata){
                formattedData = mydata.map(function (record){
                        record.url = '/'+ record.Id;
                        return record;
                });
            }

                cmp.set('v.mydata', formattedData);
            }
            else if(state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.error(errors);
            }
        }));

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Using current implementation of DataTable I was not able to open a url on click of Contact name but we can create a additional column on click on which we can open contact.

```
({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set('v.columns', [
                {label: 'Contact Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'phone'},
                {label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'email'},
                {label: 'Contact Url', fieldName: 'url', type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label:'open contact',target: '_blank'}}
            ]);

        helper.getData(cmp);
    }
})
```

You will have to transform your data to create a url

```
({
    getData : function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get('c.getContacts'); // Just a simple SOQL.

        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();

            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                var mydata = response.getReturnValue();
                var formattedData;
                if(mydata){
                   formattedData = mydata.map(function (data){
                        return data.url = '/'+ data.id;
                   })
                }
                cmp.set('v.mydata', );
            }
            else if(state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.error(errors);
            }
        }));

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it with

> lightning:datatable

but if you go the long way around and build a table using for example:

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
```

as long as you query the record id you can always do something like this:

```
 <th scope="row">
 <div class="slds-truncate"><a href="{!'/one/one.app?#/sObject/'+ object.Id + '/view'}" class="slds-text-link_reset">{!object.Name}</a></div>
 </th>
```

here is a link to the [table](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/#content) component from the slds page

hope that helps a bit!

Comment: I've seen that in other posts, and it works... I wanted to do it with the datatable just for the sake of avoiding all the css managing. Thanks for the heads up tho :-)

Comment: Do not use direct links in Lightning components. The URL format is not guaranteed to stay the same. In fact, it is changing in Summer 18 https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000269064&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: @Aidan well, you can always simply input `https://yourorg.lightning.force.com/{recordId}` and it redirects you, but yeah, you have a point.

Comment: I wouldn't even do that. The newest version of Lightning opens new records in sub-tabs. You'll confuse users with non-standard behaviour if you do any direct linking of the entire window instead of using the e.force:navigateToSObject event. Also, your link might not work in communities, or lightning-out. It's clunky, but you can just build your own custom component to encapsulate the required Javascript, then never worry about it again.

Comment: @Aidan I wasn't aware of the e.force:navigateToSObject but that is a much cleaner way of doing it, specially with the changes coming up so thanks for the shout